# Magnolia Publication status column

Tags: content-management-system, customization, magnolia

I'm working with Magnolia 5.3 and I want to add the status column in all the apps. This status column shows if a page o resource has been published. I've tried [this](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Customizing+an+app) but it hasn't worked. In the next picture you can see how I see the page app:

[image]

You can see the status column as it should be in this picture:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pages app you will not see a status column if you are logged in to a public instance. This is because the content MUST be published if it visible on the public instance.

Are you looking at a public instance when you see the view above?

Examples:

- Author Instance
  https://demo.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:pages:;
- Public Instance
  https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com/.magnolia/admincentral#app:pages:;

Comment: Yes, you're right! It's a public instance. How should I work? Should I work with a public and a private instance?

Comment: What I mean is: Do I need to have a private and a public instance to be able to do the publish mechanism?

Comment: You could develop on just an author instance with no subscribers configured if you wanted to see the publishing mechanism managing states. If you actually want to serve content then you will need an author and public - The author will only ever serve the latest content, not just content that has been published. This might help: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Instances

Answer (score 0):

Which apps? All the system apps already have the status column? I guess you mean your own apps. Do they also need buttons on the right to publish and unpublish? Take the contact app as an example and copy from there

Comment: I've updated my Post so you can see that I can't really see that column.